# Set splashscreen delay on Meteor Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, meteor

How can I set the splashscreen delay on a meteor project?

I tried

```
App.setPreference('SplashScreenDelay', '1000');
```

but this is not working. The default delay is now approx 25 seconds.

Comment: Follow below link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

Comment: i already saw that link.How to add  **meteor.config.js**  file to set delay ?

Comment: Follow this link for setting delay https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

Comment: thank you for your helps. i also saw that link.but i said that about correct wirite code about meteor js mobile-config.js file .i got asnwer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a Correct answer about Meteor Js. File Directory ***mobile-config.js*** file to add following code to set spalshscreen delay .

```
App.setPreference('AutoHideSplashScreen', 'true');
App.setPreference('SplashScreenDelay', '5000'); //5 seconds delay
```